# Update schema from [System.Activities.DurableInstancing] to my custom schema

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I'm using workflow 4.5 and in built SQL scripts to store instances and load and other operations. But I need to update my custome schema instead of using defined schema `[System.Activities.DurableInstancing]`. Can any one help me out?

Scripts use are

1. SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreLogic
2. SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema
3. SqlPersistenceProviderSchema
4. SqlPersistenceProviderLogic

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Promoted Properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff642473(v=vs.110).aspx